# Google Cloud PubSub throughput

Tags: python, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am subscribing to a subscription that can have up to 20 million updates per day, so around 230 updates/second. I want to be able to keep up with this flow. I am finding that if I have multiple instances of my PYTHON app (subscribers) running in my Kubernetes cluster, I can process more messages overall, but only up to a point. There comes a point where adding more nodes does not increase my processing power and large queues start to build up after 100 updates/sec. I would like to know why this is happening. Also, if I had multiple subscribers to the same topic in a process, would it help (I wouldn't think so)? Would it be better to partition the updates over multiple topics and subscribe to both in my app, thus giving each its own pubsub queue? Thank you so much!

Comment: Some details are missing: your subscribers are connected to a subscription or to a topic? If to a  subscription, what's the subscription type? Did you have changed the PubSub default configuration?

Comment: Cloud Pub/Sub is designed to scale to millions of messages per second, so it sounds like something must be a bottleneck in your subscribers themselves. However, it's really hard to debug in great detail in a place like Stack Overflow without seeing the code and the settings of your subscription. This question might be better suited as a GCP support request so that more information can be gathered and backend graphs can be examined.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In the pubsub callback, I make a call to one of multiple http triggered cloud functions. After reading Kamal's response, I noticed that even if the cloud function does its job quickly, there is still a certain amount of hhtp call overhead (few 100 ms), that I can't avoid. So this is the bottleneck at high data rates. At low rates this is not a problem. So thank you for guiding me in that direction! I am now thinking of having PubSub triggered cloud functions instead so I will just put a message on a topic for one of the cloud functions and return from my callback immediately.